# merge two dataframes with nested dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**How can we merge two dataframes with columns which having nested dictionaries.** Update the df1 with df2 in "actions" column. Is there any way to achieve this by using available methods like concat,append and merge..?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    {
        "id": "87c4b5a0db9f49c49f766436c9582297",
        "actions": {
            "sample": [
                {
                    "tagvalue": "test",
                    "status": "created"
                },
                {
                    "tagvalue": "test2",
                    "status": "created"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "87c4b5a0db9f49c49f766436c9582298",
        "actions": {
            "sample": [
                {
                    "tagvalue": "test2",
                    "status": "created"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
])


df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    {
        "id": "87c4b5a0db9f49c49f766436c9582297",
        "actions": {
            "sample": [
                {
                    "tagvalue": "test",
                    "status": "updated"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
])

df1.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('id', inplace=True)


# Need to merge the data based on id
# TODO : Right way to merge to get the following output

finalOutputExpectaion = [
    {
        "id": "87c4b5a0db9f49c49f766436c9582297",
        "actions": {
            "sample": [
                {
                    "tagvalue": "test",
                    "status": "updated"
                },
                {
                    "tagvalue": "test2",
                    "status": "created"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "87c4b5a0db9f49c49f766436c9582298",
        "actions": {
            "sample": [
                {
                    "tagvalue": "test2",
                    "status": "created"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

**Note : finalOutputExpectaion- updated dataframe as dict(We'll get it by using to_dict(orient=records))
Python Version : 3.7,
Pandas Version : 1.1.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `join` the dataframes `df1` and `df2` on `id`, then inside a list comprehension `zip` the column `actions` from left and right dataframe and use a custom defined `merge` function to update the dictionaries:

```
def merge(d1, d2):
    if pd.isna(d1) or pd.isna(d2):
        return d1

    tags = set(d['tagvalue'] for d in d2['sample'])
    d2['sample'] += [d for d in d1['sample'] if d['tagvalue'] not in tags]
    return d2

m = df1.join(df2, lsuffix='', rsuffix='_r')
df1['actions'] = [merge(*v) for v in zip(m['actions'], m['actions_r'])]
```

Result:

```
                                  actions
id                                                                                                                                   
87c4b5a0db9f49c49f766436c9582297  {'sample': [{'tagvalue': 'test', 'status': 'updated'}, {'tagvalue': 'test2', 'status': 'created'}]}
87c4b5a0db9f49c49f766436c9582298                                             {'sample': [{'tagvalue': 'test2', 'status': 'created'}]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Is there any way to achieve this without intermediate dataframe..?

Comment: I guess you are talking about the merged dataframe `m`?